# NullPointerException in custom Interceptor

Tags: java, struts2

I am new struts framework.here i am trying to create custom Interceptor i just converting given username to uppercase and displaying it in jsp.

My **index.jsp** code is :

`<s:form action="login">
<s:textfield name="name" label="UserName"></s:textfield>
<s:submit value="Submit"></s:submit>
</s:form>`

**Interceptor** code is :

```
    public class CustomInterceptorExample implements Interceptor
{

    @Override
    public void destroy() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void init() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Custom Interceptor called.....");
    }

    @Override
    public String intercept(ActionInvocation ai) throws Exception
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ValueStack vs=ai.getStack();
        String name=vs.findString("name"); //here i am getting exception
        System.out.println(name);
        vs.set("name", name.toUpperCase());
        System.out.println("intercept() called..."+ai.invoke());
        return ai.invoke();
    }

}
```

Struts.xml code is :

```
<struts>
 <package name="default" extends="struts-default">

<interceptors>
<interceptor name="logerName" class="com.strutsLearner.CustomInterceptorExample"></interceptor>
</interceptors>    

<action name="product" class="com.strutsLearner.Product">
<result name="success">welcome.jsp</result>
</action>

<action name="login" class="com.strutsLearner.Login">
<interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>  
<interceptor-ref name="logerName"></interceptor-ref>
<result>LogResult.jsp</result>  
</action>
</package>
</struts>
```

Stack trace is :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.strutsLearner.CustomInterceptorExample.intercept(CustomInterceptorExample.java:31)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:488)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
```

Can anyone tell me where i made mistake.

Comment: I think Vs is null that means that ai.getStack() returns a Null- Pointer. Please post the full stacktrace.

Comment: Hi @pL4Gu33 thank you for your replay.i added stacktrace to my question

Comment: i think line 31 in class CustomInterceptorExample is this "String name=vs.findString("name");" or ? That means that "ai.getStack()" null returns.

Comment: yes.but why i am getting this exception i configure every thing correctly.but name value is null

Answer (score 0):

You need to write **defaultStack** interceptor in your **stuts.xml** file

```
<interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
```